# Read json array from appsettings c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, appsettings

I have array in my `appsettings.json`

```
"steps": [
{
  "name": "IMPORT",
  "enabled": true
},
{
  "name": "IMPORT_XML",
  "enabled": true
},
{
  "name": "COMPARE",
  "enabled": true
},
{
  "test_name": "COMPARE_TABLE",
  "enabled": true
}]
```

In my class I am trying to retrieve it using `IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot`

I've tried:

```
var procSteps = _configurationRoot.GetSection("steps");
foreach (IConfigurationSection section in procSteps.GetChildren())
{
    var key = section.GetValue<string>("test");
    var value = section.GetValue<string>("enabled");
}
```

and:

```
var procSteps = _configurationRoot.GetSection("ExecutionSteps")
            .GetChildren()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToArray();
```

But none of them retrieved me values of it. Does anyone know what's the case and what is the correct way to access values of such array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an object model to hold the values

```
public class ProcessStep {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then get the array from the section using `Get<T>`

```
ProcessStep[] procSteps = _configurationRoot
    .GetSection("steps")
    .Get<ProcessStep[]>();
```

> ASP.NET Core 1.1 and higher can use `Get<T>`, which works with entire sections. `Get<T>` can be more convenient than using `Bind`

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#bind-to-an-object-graph)

Comment: I get the error: "IConfiguration/IConfigurationSection does not contain a definition for Get"

Comment: @zameb you are most likely missing a using reference for the extension method.